# How can I check the total contents of chrome.storage?

Tags: api, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, storage

In the chrome developer tools you can switch between different contexts in the javascript console and individually query the `chrome.storage.local.get()` and `chrome.storage.sync.get()` APIs. Is there a way to view the totality of what is stored there for all of chrome?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at source code of API

```
bool StorageGetFunction::RunWithStorage(ValueStore* storage) {
  Value* input = NULL;
  EXTENSION_FUNCTION_VALIDATE(args_->Get(0, &input));

  switch (input->GetType()) {
    case Value::TYPE_NULL:
      return UseReadResult(storage->Get());

    case Value::TYPE_STRING: {
      std::string as_string;
      input->GetAsString(&as_string);
      return UseReadResult(storage->Get(as_string));
    }

    case Value::TYPE_LIST: {
      std::vector<std::string> as_string_list;
      AddAllStringValues(*static_cast<ListValue*>(input), &as_string_list);
      return UseReadResult(storage->Get(as_string_list));
    }

    case Value::TYPE_DICTIONARY: {
      DictionaryValue* as_dict = static_cast<DictionaryValue*>(input);
      ValueStore::ReadResult result = storage->Get(GetKeys(*as_dict));
      if (result->HasError()) {
        return UseReadResult(result.Pass());
      }

      DictionaryValue* with_default_values = as_dict->DeepCopy();
      with_default_values->MergeDictionary(result->settings().get());
      return UseReadResult(
          ValueStore::MakeReadResult(with_default_values));
    }

    default:
      return UseReadResult(
          ValueStore::MakeReadResult(kUnsupportedArgumentType));
  }
}
```

storage type is used as an argument for querying results. So, till date it is not possible  to view the totality of what is stored there for all of chrome, you have to use two different queries (`chrome.storage.local.get()` and `chrome.storage.sync.get()` APIs).

Comment: Isn't the type being switched on in reference to how much data you want to get, i.e. send it a string to query one value, send it a list of strings to get multiple values, and so on? http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage.html#method-StorageArea-get You can get all the contents of local or all the contents of sync for just the current context by sending it null, but I was wondering about seeing all local/sync contents for all contexts - every extension, regular chrome, etc.

Comment: @RalfHaring: Till date no :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?
console.log(chrome.storage);

Comment: I think that returns all the methods and properties, not the actual stored data.